# Don't show ignored tags in the android app feed

Tags: feature-request, android-app, ignored-tags, android-app-feed

I have a few tags set to ignore on various sites on the network. I think the android app should filter these out of the hot & unanswered etc questions that show up on the feed.

If not removed entirely, then greyed out like on the website.

Comment: My question on this was closed as it was a duplicate of this question. Can we get some feedback from mods on this?

Comment: Do you mind if I add some of my own info to your question? Hoping to "bump" it up the page a little, as this question seems to be in no-man's land as things stand

Comment: Sure, go ahead.

Comment: Questions with ignored tags show on everywhere in android app, not only in hot /unanswered. The desktop version says that I am currently hiding some tags, but android app sadly completely ignores my ignores.